# How to use two file extensions as wildcard (*.csv or *.xml) in Azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a path in ADLS that has a range of different files including `*.csv` and `*.xml` (which is not true `xml`, it's just a `csv` with `xml` extension).

I want to copy only `*.csv` and `*.xml` files from this path to another using copy activity in ADF. Right now I only can specify one of them as wildcard in the file name of copy activity and not both.
Is there any way to specify two wildcards, like for example, `.csv or .xml`.

BTW, I might be able to use filter activity with get meta data, but this is too much if there is other ways.
This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#mapping-data-flow-properties) didn't help much too:

As I said, filtering won't work (without forEach), and that's not optimized:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way can specify two wildcards path.

According my experience, the easiest way is that you can create two copy active in one pipeline:

1. Copy active1: copy the files end with `*.csv`.
2. Copy active2: copy the files end with `*.xml`.

For your another question,there are many ways can achieve it.  You could add an if condition to filter the condition: only copy active 1 and 2 both true/succeeded:
[image]

You also could do like@Nandan said:
[image]

Comment: that is agood work around, but if I have another activity after these copies, does the next activity waits for previous copies to finish before it starts.
Lest say after two copies, I process and copy all files to to SQL DB, so I want the process stage starts after copying xml and csv.

Comment: Hey, you can use on successful completion of both the copy activities (XML, CSV) to proceed with further activities.

Comment: @mas there are many ways can achieve it. Please see my update.